# mobile.twitter.com iphone/ipad animations

Tags: mobile, twitter, frameworks

I was testing mobile.twitter.com with iphone and ipad. It feels like native app for me. I was wondering does someone know what kind of solution or framework they use for the animations?

Do the have done addons to boostrap?